# How to give user groups(XML) in the model ir.actions.server odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I used this xml code to add a button inside the 'Action',But i need to restrict the button to some user groups,

```
<record id="specialist_no_show_action" model="ir.actions.server">
                <field name="name">No Show </field>
                <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
                <field name="binding_model_id" ref="second_opinion.model_consultation"/>
                <field name="model_id" ref="second_opinion.model_consultation"/>
                <field name="state">code</field>
                <field name="code">
                    action = model.update_no_show()
                </field>
            </record>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ir.actions.actions` [get_bindings](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L98) method will try to retrieve the list of actions bound to the given model and discard unauthorized actions then read action definitions.

The method will use [groups_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L118) field to check if the user may not perform an action.

> groups_id
> Many2many field to the groups allowed to view/use the current report

So a [groups_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L118) field is added to `ir.actions.report` to allow [groups](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/actions.html#report-actions-ir-actions-report) to view/use the current report

Unfortunately, the `groups_id` field is not implemented in `ir.actions.server`

Fortunately, the `get_bindings` method is implemented in the `ir.actions.actions` model which is the base model for both models `ir.actions.report` and `ir.actions.server`, so to use the same logic in server actions just add a `groups_id` field in `ir.action.server` and use it from the XML definition to restrict access to some groups.

***Use the `groups_id` field for server action:***

- Inherit server action model and add the `groups_id` field:

  ```py
  class IrActionsServer(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'ir.actions.server'

      groups_id = fields.Many2many('res.groups', 'res_groups_server_rel', 'uid', 'gid', string='Groups')
  ```
- Then set the `groups_id` field value from XML, the following example will use the [special commands format](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/models.py#L3253) to add the `Administration/Access Rights` group to the `groups_id` field:

  ```
  <field name='groups_id' eval="[(4, ref('base.group_erp_manager'))]"/>
  ```

Comment: Would be nice Odoo implementing this to the core code. I don't know why it isn't yet, because i only see advantages and as you mentioned: everything is there anyways (except the field...)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to restrict its visibility in the action menu, but as a workaround you could do the following in the `code` of the server action:

```
if not env.user.has_group('base.group_erp_manager'):
    raise Warning("You do not have access to trigger this action")
```

Replace "base.group_erp_manager" with your user group's XML ID.